# How can I repeatedly run/burn a scenario (written in cucumber) for a specific number of times through cypress-grep?

Tags: typescript, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have installed `cypress-grep` plugin as a dev dependency so that I can run a cucumber scenario a specific number of times to check its flakiness. These are the changes I have made:

1. `yarn add -D cypress-grep` which adds this dependency in `package.json`
2. Made this entry `require('cypress-grep')()` in `cypress/support > index.js`
3. Optionally, also made the following below entry here `cypress/plugins > index.js`

   ```
   module.exports = (on, config) => {
     require('cypress-grep/src/plugin')(config)
   }
   ```
4. Now I am trying to run a scenario (title contains "hello") inside a feature file multiple times to check its flakiness `cypress/integration/folderA/sample.feature`. For this, I am executing the following command:

```
npx cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/folderA/sample.feature" --env grep=hello,burn=10
```

But every time the command runs, I get the following error:

```
The error was:

Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./cypress/integration/folderA/sample.feature 1:15
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:15)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> Feature: Feature file name
| 
|   Background: Sample background title

This occurred while Cypress was compiling and bundling your test code. This is usually caused by:

- A missing file or dependency
- A syntax error in the file or one of its dependencies

Fix the error in your code and re-run your tests.
```

I am not sure what this error is trying to tell me.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue. If you want to know how it was fixed, please refer to this issue: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-grep/issues/62